# pine script error - script could not be translated from: null

Tags: compiler-errors, bots, pine-script

My pine code (simple trading bot) is not compiling and returns the error in Tradeviews editor "Script could not be translated from: null".

I tried to compile part by part, and researched online, but failed.

Can somebody help?

Much appreciated, Thx,
Denis

---

```
if (consolidatingMarket(consolidationPeriod, consolidationThreshold))
{
if (breakoutDetected(breakoutThreshold))
{
enterLong()
}
}
else
{
exit()
}

study(title="Consolidating Market")
plot(consolidatingMarket(consolidationPeriod, consolidationThreshold))

function consolidatingMarket(period, threshold)
{
var avgRange = sma(range, period)
return range \<= avgRange \* threshold
}

study(title="Breakout Detected")
plot(breakoutDetected(breakoutThreshold))

function breakoutDetected(threshold)
{
var period = consolidationPeriod
var avgRange = sma(range, period)
return range \>= avgRange \* threshold
}

function enterLong()
{
var stopLossPrice = entryPrice \* (1 - stopLoss/100)
var takeProfitPrice = entryPrice \* (1 + takeProfit/100)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop_loss=stopLossPrice, take_profit=takeProfitPrice)
}

function exit()
{
strategy.close()
}
```

Comment: This code is far from being a valid `pinescript` code. There are way too many issues with it. I suggest you start with the [pinescript primer](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/primer/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, Vitruvius! Just starting :)

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading the pinescript manual. Your code is NOT in pinescript langage.
Read at least on time this User Manual and look how the examples are made : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html